# How to access data from callback

Tags: angularjs, q, angular-promise

I have written method called `getChildren` to get data related to id, but I am unable to access that data in caller method. My sample code is as follows

I have written these two methods in controller and Passed all objects which are necessary

```
var baseMethod = function(rootNode) {
var id = 123;

var result = getChildren(id);
};


var getChildren = function(id) {
var deferred = $q.defer();

return dummyService.oneAction(id).then(
    function (data) {
        return deferred.resolve(data);
    }
);
}
```

Whats wrong with this. I want to assign data in callback to my result. How can I do that.

Comment: Is `dummyService.oneAction` returning a promise?

Comment: Yes, it is. I am getting proper data in callback function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var result = getChildren(id).then(function(data){

angular.copy(data, $scope.child)
});
```

Comment: My flow of execution continues,but my callback didn't get called. So I am getting 'undefined' in $scope.child when I try to access it

Comment: Still same problem. If I try to use $scope.child just after this call, I get 'undefined' error. This is because callback is still not executed

Comment: Yes I did that at start of the controller

Answer (score 0):

You function **getChildren** return a promise, so try

```
var baseMethod = function(rootNode) {
  var id = 123;
  var result;

  getChildren(id).then(function(data) {
    result = data;
  });
};
```

Comment: I tried this. It is not working. My flow of execution goes forward, but callback is not got called. So I got undefined in result.